# Application to probabilities of sum of random variables

Tags: probability

[image]

### Attempt

Let $X$ be the amount of claims. I see the range of $X$ must be only $\{0,1,2 \}$ since $P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)=1$. This problem is confusing since we are given $X$ is uniform on $[0,60]$ but then we clearly see $X$ is a discrete and not a continuos r.v.

Perhaps we can write $X_i$ to be the amount in claim $i$ and then $X= X_1+X_2+X_3$ is what they mean to be uniform. Am I on the right track?

Comment: No, you are told that *claim amounts* are uniformly distributed on $[0,60]$  This is different from $X$ which is simply the number of claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of claims and $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots$ be i.i.d. with $\mathsf{Unif}(0,60)$ distribution. Let $Z$ be the total benefit paid, then for any $t\geqslant 0$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Z\leqslant t) &= \mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{i=0}^2 \{Z\leqslant t\}\cap\{X=j\} \right)\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^2\mathbb P(\{Z\leqslant t\}\cap\{X=i\})\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^2\mathbb P(X=i)\mathbb P\left(\sum_{j=1}^i Y_j\leqslant t\right)\\
&= \mathbb P(X=0) + \mathbb P(X=1)\mathbb P(Y_1\leqslant t)+\mathbb P(X=2)\mathbb P(Y_1+Y_2\leqslant t).
\end{align}
Let $f_Y$ be the density of $Y_1$, then we compute the density of $Y_1+Y_2$ by convolution:
\begin{align}
f_{Y_1+Y_2}(t) &= (f_Y\star f_Y)(t)\\
&= \int_0^t f_Y(s)f_Y(t-s)\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \int_0^t \frac1{60^2}\mathsf 1_{(0,60)}(s)\ \mathsf 1_{(0,60)}(t-s)\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \int_0^t \frac1{3600}\mathsf 1_{(0,60)}(t)\ \mathsf ds + \int_{t-60}^{60}\frac1{3600}\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \frac t{3600}\mathsf 1_{(0,60)}(t) + \left(\frac1{30} - \frac t{3600}\right)\mathsf 1_{(60,120)}(t).
\end{align}
It follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Z\leqslant t) &= \frac7{10} + \frac15\cdot\frac t{60}\mathsf 1_{(0,60)}(t) + \frac1{10}\cdot\left(\frac {t^2}{7200}\mathsf 1_{(0,60)}(t) + \left(\frac32 
 -\left(\frac t{30}-\frac{t^2}{3600}\right) \right)\mathsf 1_{(60,120)}(t) \right)\\
&= \frac7{10} + \frac{t(240+t)}{72000}\mathsf 1_{(0,60)}(t) - \frac{(t-60)(t-180)}{72000}\mathsf 1_{(60,120)}(t).
\end{align}
In particular,
$$
\mathbb P(Z\leqslant 48) = \frac7{10}+\frac{48(240+48)}{72000} = \frac{223}{250}.
$$